# Insert $index into name attribute in an ng-repeat angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In order for ASP.NET MVC to correctly bind a list of items on a form post, the name attribute has be along the lines of

```
name='Show.Days[0].OpenHour'
name='Show.Days[1].OpenHour'
```

The user can enter the number of days the show will be into a form field, which then updates the model and the ng-repeat.
I'd like to be able to insert the appropriate index into the name field, something like

```
name='Show.Days[$index].OpenHour'
```

Is this possible with angular?

Comment: Should be possible,did you try it?

Comment: @SatejS I did yes, when I inspect the elements in Chrome, it just shows [$index]

Comment: did you try with `name="{{Show.Days[$index].OpenHour}}"`

Comment: @AndrésEsguerra just tried that, spits out the name attribute with no value

Comment: @AndrésEsguerra Ah, but you led me down the right path name="Show.Days[{{$index}}].OpenHour" works. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct one. I have another angular question [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835544/angularjs-not-binding-to-numeric-value-in-select-list) if you're feeling ambitious :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `name="Show.Days[{{$index}}].OpenHour"`. With this, AngularJS evaluates `$index` and replaces it with the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you forgot to wrap the expression with `{{` and `}}` in the view. Do you need something like this?

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.Show = {
      Days: [
        {OpenHour: '8am'},
        {OpenHour: '10am'}
      ]
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="day in Show.Days">
      <input type="text" ng-model="Show.Days[$index].OpenHour" name="{{Show.Days[$index].OpenHour}}">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or like this?

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.Show = {
      Days: [
        {OpenHour: '8am'},
        {OpenHour: '10am'}
      ]
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="day in Show.Days">
      <input type="text" ng-model="Show.Days[$index].OpenHour" name="Show.Days[{{$index}}].OpenHour">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The second one, name="Show.Days[{{$index}}].OpenHour" works

Comment: @MichaelTranchida It seems I am a bit late

Comment: Gotta be quick like a rabbit on SO, thank you though :)